# Tasklets Local Storage in Stackless Python

Tags: python, stackless, python-stackless

I'm starting with Stackless Python so it's a whole new amazing world for me. 
I usually use regular threads, and they normally have Thread-local storage (TLS), which 
is a very useful feature when you need NOT share memory with other threads.

So, I'm wondering if Stackless Python has something similar: A way to store local memory
(a python object) for a given tasklet. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.
-f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution1: The TLS can be simulated in stackless/greenlet using the current tasklet object, retrieved by the call of stackless.getcurrent(), to store additional data.

Solution2: If the tasklet didn't support to add extra fields, than you can have a global [WeakKeyDictionary](http://docs.python.org/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakKeyDictionary) instance that will have as weakref key the tasklet, and value represents your TLS.